Why the Joystick not loading in flutter?
I'm developing a game using the Flame engine in Flutter, and I'm trying to add a JoystickComponent to my game. The joystick is not showing up on the screen, even though there are no errors in the console.
Here’s my Adventureofpixleman game class:
assets:

assets/tiles/
assets/images/Terrain/
assets/images/Main Characters/Mask Dude/
assets/images/Main Characters/Ninja Frog/
assets/images/Main Characters/Pink Man/
assets/images/Main Characters/Virtual Guy/
assets/images/HUD/

